# Flurl GetJsonAsync JsonSerializationException: Could not create an instance of type. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, flurl

I'm working with old code from 3 years ago to interface with Cosmos SDK (blockchain), the APIs have changed and I'm having trouble deserializing a JSON from GetJsonAsnyc() method. See code below. I have an interface, IAccount and a class BaseAccount that implements the interface.

```
await clientResponse.GetJsonAsync<IAccount>()
```

**Here's the JSON:**

```
{
  "account": {
    "@type": "/cosmos.auth.v1beta1.BaseAccount",
    "address": "cosmos1lmgm2eta9wpyr75k5740a802p07mfg3x843pzt",
    "pub_key": {
      "@type": "/cosmos.crypto.secp256k1.PubKey",
      "key": "AumYB1B2M6HVoVeSG40VVwAq+Lut8qKOsG80mcUrJhx/"
    },
    "account_number": "0",
    "sequence": "1"
  }
}
```

**The Interface:**

```
public interface IAccount
{
    public PublicKey GetPublicKey();
    public ulong GetSequence();
    public ulong GetAccountNumber();
}
```

**The Implementation:**

```
public class BaseAccount : IAccount
{
    public BaseAccount()
    {
    }
    public BaseAccount(string type, string address, PublicKey publicKey, ulong accountNumber, ulong sequence)
    {
        Type = type;
        Address = address;
        PublicKey = publicKey;
        AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        Sequence = sequence;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "account_number")]
    public ulong AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "address")]
    public string Address { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "pub_key")]
    public PublicKey PublicKey { get; set; } = null!;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sequence")]
    public ulong Sequence { get; set; }

    public PublicKey GetPublicKey()
    {
        return new PublicKey()
        {
            Type = null,
            Key = PublicKey.Key
        };
    }
    public ulong GetSequence()
    {
        return Sequence;
    }
    public ulong GetAccountNumber()
    {
        return AccountNumber;
    }
}
```

I also tried await `clientResponse.GetJsonAsync\<BaseAccount\>()` but it returns  empty values. I'm using Flurl library and .NET6

Answer (score 0):

You can not deserialize to an interface. Also you have to add a root class

```
  await clientResponse.GetJsonAsync<Data>()

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("account")]
    public BaseAccount Account { get; set; }
}
```

and fix a type property

```
    [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
```

if it still doesnt work properly, it is better to use something like this (convert it to flurl). In this case you don't need a root class

```
    var response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
   var json =  await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   IAccount account =JObject.Parse(json)["account"].ToObject<BaseAccount>();
```

Comment: Thanks Serge, this works! Not sure if it worked before in the original code, which was written three years ago --> return _clientGetter().Request("auth", "accounts", address)
                .GetJsonAsync<ResponseWithHeight<IAccount>>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken)
                .WrapExceptions();